# how to get rows in reverse sorted order using pycassa get_range?

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

I want to get the rows returned by get_range in pycassa to be in reverse sorted order..i.e. from finish to start.
I know that there exists a parameter column_reversed for getting columns in reverse sorted order , but how do i get this done for rows?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra itself doesn't support getting a range of rows in reverse order.  It also doesn't support getting rows in normal sorted order unless you're using an order preserving partitioner, which is almost never recommended.  This post is a bit old, but still covers the topic quite well: http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/cassandra-randompartitioner-vs-orderpreservingpartitioner/